# Implementing a Conversation view without saving the user name

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-10, chatroom

I am making a public chat room in my application and i want the messages that the other users send is on the left side of the screen and the message that the user send is on the right side like any other app the problem here is how can i differ these messages when i retrieve them from the database?

Comment: Surely you must be saving something to identify who sent the message?

Comment: You can't analyze on data which you didn't save

Comment: What kind of app are you developing?